# Why is my PSD file corrupted?

Tags: ios, krita

I made this in Medibang Paint on my iPhone, then used [MediaConvert](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/media-converter-video-to-mp3/id1294207675) to send this over to my laptop, then edited it in krita, saved it as a PSD file, but when I opened it in Adobe Animate, I get this error:
"The import did not finish because an unknown error occurred"

So I sent the edited image back to my phone using Discord, but when I opened it in Medibang Paint, it looked like this:

[image: Corrupted image]

Any ideas why?
[The image in question](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/756594233195888776/1108442760274509914/itsoutchy_impostor.psd)

Comment: "Why" questions don't work on stack exchange, because we cannot ever see what actually went wrong. Judging by your posted file, something at some unknown point, went very badly wrong. Go back to your original file & either try again, or use a different path to your proposed end-point.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have solved this by editing it on my phone, seems like it was because of Krita. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm glad you go it  :) We don't do "solved" in the question title like reddit. if we have an answer it needs to go in the answer space… though in this case I think the question will just end up being closed, as it's not really something that could have been answered in a way that others would be able to find useful in future. Stick round though & see if you can find other questions/answers useful to you. :)